# Registering Bind event as DOMNodeInserted in document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following actions in my document.ready. 
What I'm trying to do is to selectively remove a div with ID that ends with '`_View_memberDirectory`'. Therefore, I'm adding the following code which works if it's not part of my function below. However, when I have it inside my function it does not work. At the moment the boolean is always `true`. Any ideas?

```
$("[id$='_View_memberDirectory']").bind('DOMNodeInserted', function (event) {
      $(this).empty();
});
```

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(function () {
            var bIsContact;
            bIsContact = IsContact();
            if (bIsContact.responseText === "true") {
                     //does not work here
                $("[id$='_View_memberDirectory']").bind('DOMNodeInserted', function (event) {
                    $(this).empty();
                });

            }
            else {
                e.preventDefault;
            }
        });

      //works here <-------
    });
```

Edit: Added IsContact() function

```
function IsContact() {
        var friendId =  <%= Request.QueryString("UserID").ToString()%> + '';
        var sf = $.ServicesFramework(<%=ModuleId %>);
        var serviceUrl = sf.getServiceRoot('OmniBody');
        var obj = { "friendId": friendId };

        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: serviceUrl + "/ModuleTask/IsContact",
            beforeSend: sf.setModuleHeaders,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj)
        }).done(function (result) {

        }).fail(function (xhr, result, status) {
            alert(result);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `$(function () {` inside another DOM ready handler? remove it and can you show the code of `IsContact()`?

Comment: @Satpal I have removed it. It still doesn't work.

Comment: `e.preventDefault;` ????

Comment: @Satpal I have added the function

Comment: @alwaysVBNET ajax is async. I have really no idea of what you are trying to do

Comment: @A.Wolff I have added in my ajax call  async: false, and this made it work. If you answer this question I will mark it as accepted. Great!

Comment: You should go through [How to return the response from an AJAX call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

it is not recommended to use `async: false` in AJAX call

instead, you can try like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {
        var bIsContact;
        IsContact().done(function(result) {
            if (result) { // assuming result is boolean value

                // do your stuff here
                $("[id$='_View_memberDirectory']").bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
                    $(this).empty();
                });

            } else {
                //something elase
            }
        }).fail(function(xhr, result, status) {
            alert(result);
        });
    });

    //works here <-------
});

function IsContact() {
    var friendId = <%= Request.QueryString("UserID").ToString()%> + '';
    var sf = $.ServicesFramework(<%=ModuleId %>);
    var serviceUrl = sf.getServiceRoot('OmniBody');
    var obj = {
        "friendId": friendId
    };
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: serviceUrl + "/ModuleTask/IsContact",
        beforeSend: sf.setModuleHeaders,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj)
    });
}
```

Comment: it's a string boolean i.e. "true"

Comment: it doesn't work. It has the same effect as the original problem.

Comment: whats the error? is your AJAX call working properly? are you getting "result" inside the done function?

Comment: yes, It's getting into the 'True' clause but then even if the event is registered the div still appears.

Comment: are you trying to empty the div when you get result === "true", or trying to attach an event which emptys the div only when something gets inserted in to it?

Comment: that div is a part of a module which appears depending on other conditions. The div might appear later, so I am trying to register the event which emptys it as soon as it appears.